# Entity Framework: Parent Child & Inter-child relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I'm new to the entity framework and database relationships. I've created an entity framework code first model, and managed to get a working hierarchical structure in place. I'm however struggling with my inter-child relationships. The structure is as follows:

1. Parent Object

1.1 "ChildA" children (can have any number of these)

1.2 "ChildB" children (can have any number of these)

"ChildA" and "ChildB" therefore share the same parent object. If the parent is deleted, both of these collections will be deleted as well. Now the part that I'm struggling with. How can I define a relationship between "ChildA" and "ChildB"?

"ChildB" references an instance of "ChildA", and I want this to be 'on the same level', i.e. "ChildA" isn't necessarily the parent of "ChildB". Is this possible, or will "ChildA" have to be the parent of "ChildB"? The reason that I don't want to establish a parent relationship here, is due to the fact that other children can be introduced on this level, e.g. "ChildB" can refer to an instance of "ChildA", "ChildC" and "ChildD". The relationship from "ChildB" to one (or more) other children will always be one-way, i.e. "ChildB" will extract information from the other children and use it internally.

The current code:

```
Public class Parent 
{
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public virtual ObservableCollection<ChildA> ChildrenA {get;set;}
    public virtual ObservableCollection<ChildB> ChildrenB {get;set;}
}

public class ChildA
{
    public int ChildAID {get;set;}
}

Public class ChildB
{
    public int ChildBID {get;set;}
    public ChildA childA {get;set;}
    public int childAID {get;set;}
    [...some calculations using values/references from childA...]
}

[...More of these children defined...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to create is a one-to-one relationship between `ChildA` and `ChildB`, therefore you have to tell EF how this relationship will work.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>()
        .HasOptional<ChildB>(u => u.ChilbB)
        .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.ChildA).Map(p => p.MapKey("ChildAID"));
```

Have a look at the documentation for further info:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx